# How to format, yyyymmdd to yyyy-mm-dd in Logstash?

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok, elastic-stack, logstash-configuration

I've started working around with the `ELK tool stack` since few weeks. What I need is to get the `timestamp` of the log event which includes date and the time and show it in a different field (ie: log_timestamp). I've tried pulling out all the options available for the DateStamp, but nothing worked.

This is a line of the log file which I have:

"**20160805 00:00:01.296,GetProvisioning,3,W1oOOW8oj58GhglVjVNg0Ssl4CXA1P,50219--1958335734-1470326399706,SUCCESS,GetProvisioningTransactionId-01223,null,W1oOOW8oj58GhglVjVNg0Ssl4CXA1P,en,CELCOM_MY_DCB**
"

I need to format the date of the log event as `yyyy-mm-dd`, since i'm unable to use the  "Date"  grok filters. Or is there a way that I can filter it out with the above `yyyymmdd` date format?

**EDIT**:
I'm hereby attaching my customized pattern and the filter part of the `logstash conf`.

pattern which I'm using: **LOGTIMESTAMP %{YEAR}%{MONTHNUM}%{MONTHDAY}**

The filter criteria in logstash conf:

```
filter {

        grok {
            patterns_dir => ["/home/chamith/work/ELK/logstash/logstash-2.3.4/bin/patterns"]
            match => { "message" => "%{GREEDYDATA} %{LOGTIMESTAMP:logtimestamp}" }  

        }
        mutate {
            add_field => {
                "timestamp" => "%{LOGTIMESTAMP}"
            }
            remove_field => ["logtimestamp"]
        }
        date {
            match => ["logtimestamp", "yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss"]
            target => "logtimestamp"
        }           
     }
```

and the output in Kibana:

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: So you want to have your `20160805 00:00:01.296` timestamp as logstash timestamp for this event?

Comment: Yes and I need to have the timestamp above as `2016-08-05 00:00:01.296`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `date` filter to parse timestamps. If you want to avoid writing custom regex for `grok` you could combine the two fields and use the `date` filter.

For your paticular example:

```
grok {
    match => { "message" => "%{POSINT:time1} %{TIME:time2} ... <Rest goes here> }
}
mutate {
    add_field => {
        "timestamp" => "%{time1} %{time2}"
    }
    remove_field => ["time1", "time2"]
}
date {
    match => { "timestamp" => ""yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss.SSS }
}
```

This will pretty much get the timestring and put it in the `@timestamp` field.

Comment: And if you don't want to put the resulting timestring in the `@timestamp` field, you can use the [`target` setting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-date.html#plugins-filters-date-target) : `target => log_timestamp`

Comment: @Fairy Thank you for the reply. Tried out with my custom pattern. But couldn't get the exact output (yyyy-mm-dd). Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: Your grok pattern can't match at all, thats why you have a tag `_grokparsefailure`. Your pattern should look like this: `%{POSINT:time1} %{TIME:time2}%{GREEDYDATA}`

Comment: You're a life saver. It works! Btw how could I create a `date` field such as the original `@timestamp` rather than a `string`?